# GitPlugin for Trac doesn't work every few requests

Tags: git, trac

I've set up and configured Trac with the GitPlugin (http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/GitPlugin) but for some reason every three or so requests to Trac pages, I get the error:

```
Unsupported version control system "git". Check that the Python support libraries for "git" are correctly installed.
```

After a refresh or two, it goes along happily being able to browse the source and view commits in the timeline. I thought this might be an issue with the cached_repository flag, but disabling that doesn't help.

I don't even know where to start troubleshooting this, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intermittent nature of the thing looks like an issue with different instances of your web server seeing different bits configuration. The very first thing I'd try is restarting everything (a reboot isn't *necessary* but it is the simplest way to make sure *everything* gets restarted). If that doesn't work, then at least you know you've eliminated the easy stuff.

Comment: Restarting Apache did the trick. I thought I had done that, but I guess you can miss the easy stuff sometimes. Thanks!